# How to add @ mention in response to slash commands in slack

Tags: slack-api, slack

How can I make slack parse `@someone` mentions as links to the user instead of plaintext. I've been reading slack documentation on message formatting but still haven't figured it out. Here's an example of what I'm getting now:

```
{
  "text": "*username:* @alexis",
  "response_type": "ephemeral"
}
```

[image: mention not parsed as link]

Comment: I have the same question with yours, and I think this will work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771924/how-to-mention-user-in-slack-client/40774442#40774442

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To make a proper "clickable" mention, you need to pass the unique user ID and not the plaintext name.

The format of the user ID is: `U024BE7LH`and a mention would look like this: `<@U024BE7LH>`

Ther user ID of the user that executed the slash command will be in the payload that slack sends to your endpoint. You can also look up user IDs by calling the [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) method, which will give you access to the user IDs of all the users in the team.

More information [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users)

Comment: You can use username as well `<@username>` , Not just the unique ID

Comment: You can no longer use `@username` (since Sept 2017).  I realize the comment I'm responding to is older than that, just want to clarify for future readers who find their way here.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the username inside `<>` quotes like this `<@someone>`

Sample

```
{
  "text": "*username:* <@alexis>",
  "response_type": "ephemeral"
}
```

Also if instead of user you want to notify channel then use `!channel`, `!group` , `!here` , or `!everyone` instead of `@username`

For eg.

```
{
  "text": "*username:* <!channel>",
  "response_type": "ephemeral"
}
```

Comment: This answer is in part outdated. Slack is phasing out `@username` and developers should user @user-Id instead. More info here: https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames

Comment: This solution no longer works unless you get the actual user ID, which is not the same thing as what you type when you `@someone` in a chat window, especially if the user was created since they made the change (sept 2017).

Answer (score 0):

```
slack_web_client.chat_postMessage(
    channel="channel_name",
    text="Hi! <@User_id>"
)
```

Place User ID in **<>** quotes and make sure that your app/bot has Scopes for **commands**.

Further details - https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands