# How to mention user in slack.client

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

This might be a simple question, but I can not get it work.

I am using Slack Python Api to mention a user in a channel, and I am referring to the document here, https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage, and my code is simple as,

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
sc = SlackClient(token)
message = sc.api_call(
  'chat.postMessage',
  channel='#channelname',
  text='This is a test.'
  )
```

This will send a message to the channel, but I can not find any option to mention users. And I tried to put `@someone` inside the message such as

```
 text='@someone This is a test.'
```

The message will be posted but in plain text, not really mentioning someone.
BTW, I am using a Test Token.(Or maybe this feature is only available for authorized token? )

Is there any option or method to do this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414427/how-to-add-mention-in-response-to-slash-commands-in-slack/36463098#36463098

Comment: @WilhelmKlopp thank you for the suggest. It helps. However, the `user_name` will be changing the bot showing name, not mentioning someone in the message. I posted my answer below and believe we don't need to get the user ID in that case.

Comment: Note that slack has offered many different ways to mention users via API over the years, [but has since deprecated most of them](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames). The best choice is to use `<@U123>` syntax, and if you need to look up the user-id to hard-code it into a message, you may need to make a one-time request to [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) to retrieve the correct ID value

Answer (score 64, accepted):

After a little bit exploration, I got the solution which is quite simple. I don't know how I could miss it.

```
message = sc.api_call(
  'chat.postMessage',
  link_names=1,
  channel='#channelname',
  text='@someone This is a test.'
  )
```

use the option `link_names=1` to link channels or user names automatically in the text message. This will do the trick.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: The real question is: why isn't the default for link_names set to 1?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ScottieB might be a good idea to mention it to the development team. :)

Comment: `link_names` can also be set to True/False which makes a little more sense then setting it to 0 or 1.

Comment: Use `<@userID>` instead. This method doesn't work when mentioning more than 1 user.

Comment: @marengaz the feeling I get after reading (pretty much all) slack documentation is that userId is preferred, generally speaking. 
However I was able to get two mentions in a chat_postMessage method (although I'm using https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client )

text: ": <@#{slack_user_name}> <@testuser>",

And it worked fine

Comment: sorry @JohnZaj, i was a little ambiguous. when i said "This method ..." i was referring to `text='@someone This is a test.'`, as in the answer. i have the same findings as you, in that, 2 mentions work correctly with the <> brackets

Comment: For anyone that wants to notify a user via an incoming webhook, setting `link_names: true` in REST payload also does the trick. Even though this is not documented...

Comment: `link_names` is deprecated use `<@userID>` instead

Answer (score 98):

Posting an updated answer as this method no longer works since Slack updated their API. Now you have to discover the user's ID using `users.list`, or just looking it up in the Slack app on their profile.

Then for a given *userID*, you mention them by setting the text as follows: <@*userID*>. The `link_names` argument is now irrelevant. So this would be the code to use now:

```
message = sc.api_call(
  'chat.postMessage',
  channel='#channelname',
  text='<@userID> This is a test.'
  )
```

HOWEVER, if you want to mention a usergroup, then the old method still applies - just @mention them and in that case *do* set `link_names` to true.

Comment: Note that the @userID is not the user's handle or display name.  It's an underlying identifier https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, this method doesn't work if you use the "Bot User OAuth Token".  You must use "User OAuth Token" or the at-mention is ignored.

Comment: Here is a doc link for mentioning users: https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-users

Comment: Curious if you know the format for a slack user group/list? would it be the same?