# Laravel notification add mention of user in group channel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to send a notification with a mention of a user in a general channel. This is what I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class WeeklyTasksResponsible extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $employee;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(\App\Employee $employee)
    {
        $this->employee = $employee;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['slack'];
    }


    /**
     * Get the Slack representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return SlackMessage
     */
    public function toSlack($notifiable)
    {
        return (new SlackMessage)
            ->content('Reponsible for this week is: ' . $this->employee->slack_name);
    }
}
```

This will sent a weekly notification in the general slack channel of our company. The message is "Responsible for this week is: nameofuser". The problem is the user doesn't see a notification of this.

I've also tried do this:

```
public function toSlack($notifiable)
{
    return (new SlackMessage)
        ->content('Reponsible for this week is: @' . $this->employee->slack_name);
}
```

But it isn't the same as mentioning someone myself in the channel.

How can I do this?

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage), you have to set the `link_names` parameter to `true`/`1`. I don't have enough time to give you the solution myself, hope someone can help you. You can see an explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774442/7117697) answer.

Comment: Or just use the user ID instead of the user name and it should work. e.g. `<@U12345678>`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @HCK you can enable matching of usernames for `@username` mentions in [`chat.postMessages`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) by setting the optional parameter `link_names` to `true`.

However, creating mentions with usernames is deprecated and should no longer be used.

The recommended approach is to create mentions with the user ID, which will work by default.

Example:

```
<@U12345678>
```

See the post [A lingering farewell to the username](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames) from Slack for details about username deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the following in the Laravel 6.18.0 source code:

```php
    /**
     * Find and link channel names and usernames.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function linkNames()
    {
        $this->linkNames = 1;

        return $this;
    }
```

`vendor/laravel/slack-notification-channel/src/Messages/SlackMessage.php`

So you can use it like this:

```php
public function toSlack($notifiable)
    {
        return (new SlackMessage)
        ->linkNames()
        ...
    }
```

As @erik-kalkoken pointed out, use the Slack user ID, enclosed by `<>` and with the `@` sign. You can find it in your profile in the Slack App:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I tried that way and it's works pretty well.

```
$content .= "New order!\r\n @person";

return (new SlackMessage)
            ->content($content)->linkNames();
```

You would need to add the **@** before name of person or team and in order for slack to recognize them as mentions not just text, you would need to chain the content with **linkNames**